# How do I revise the existing Index query to have the results be returned in the appropriate columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

The current Index queries (see Index sheet, columns W2 & AD2) are
returning the results appropriately in the Index, but when the
results are retrieved by other sheets (Administrative view, Grade
Level Dashboard), the results are spilling over Horizontally
(screen-shot).

See [Dummy Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19Vp-hTQst8ucFXT4CwUJm66BrT9JH9bzo8alCHESv8Y/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYKGR.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Recommendation:**

Add 1 in the header parameter for the query to determine that there's only 1 header row at the top of your data.

For STANDARD:

```
=QUERY(Index!T2:Z36031, "SELECT W, X, T WHERE W IS NOT NULL ",1)
```

For CROSS CUTTING CONCEPT:

```
=QUERY(Index!T2:AA36031, "SELECT AA, X, T WHERE X IS NOT NULL ",1)
```

**Reference:**

[Query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have any questions with respect to the answer posted above. Also, about your follow up question regarding adding column for module, I'm afraid that it already counts as another question / post. I recommend that you post it as a new question so the community can help you. Thank you.